Why we need sync_to_async in Django?
The document said:

The reason this is needed in Django is that many libraries, specifically database adapters, require that they are accessed in the same thread that they were created in. Also a lot of existing Django code assumes it all runs in the same thread, e.g. middleware adding things to a request for later use in views.

But another question Is it safe that when Two asyncio tasks access the same awaitable object? said python's asyncio is thread safe.
And as I know since the GIL still exist accessing one object from multiple thread should be thread safe.
Can any one give a minimal example for why we have to use await sync_to_async(foo)() instead of directly foo() in django or other async apps?
This question(How does sync_to_async convert sync functions to async) does not answer my question, in this example use sync_to_async does not show any significant difference, the order of function calls inside second_job is the same. And have nothing to do with avoid serious conflict.
I know who sync_to_async works, but why we need to run sync function in a new thread in async context?

If the other answer wasn't clear, it's a way to effectively stop the synchronous function from blocking the async function from running - see that wait start and wait finish in the first example being sequential and has blocked the async function from doing anything else for the 3 seconds it was in synchronous sleep.

@metatoaster, I know that, but performance is not mentioned in django's document and can be solved by multi-thread server just like we do in sync environment. What they most concerned is edit same object which I cannot understand.

Not really, multi-threaded async servers can still block if it doesn't move all synchronous functions (there is no guarantee that they don't block synchronously) out to a dedicated thread-pool for potentially blocking synchronous tasks.

@metatoaster, why? For example, use time.sleep in a view function, so if someone view the endpoint the thread is blocked but if the server started with 8 workers or even 8 pods, the rest 7 instance will work as normal. In this case, things won't get worse if developer change the slow view from sync to async.

If you got 8 additional requests to that very same view function, one of them will block. For a more practical example, imagine a particular view needing results from an internal legacy API that will block, and went non-responsive and not return. Now a hundred requests comes in for that view (e.g. a bot) which will render the application non-responsive. If those blocking calls are moved to a different thread that doesn't cause your worker threads to block, they can still function and respond to other incoming requests to unaffected views, so only the view needing the legacy API will be down.

@metatoaster, but this case is a structure bug, it will also happen to a sync web app. My question is based on a healthy sync web app migrating to async. If a sync function call is healthy, create a new thread for it is likely consume more resource than call it simply.

You are making false assumptions about what's healthy or not. You also have a misconception that sync_to_async always creates a new thread. It typically does not in ordinary usage, it only moves the sync function into a dedicated shared thread that was already pre-allocated if it's already called within an existing async context - quoting documentation: "If you use asyncio.run() or similar, it will fall back to running thread-sensitive functions in a single, shared thread, but this will not be the main thread."

Django in fact uses sync_to_async in many places internally, from database access (which may be fully synchronous, e.g. sqlite) to generating error pages from exceptions. Using sync_to_async ensures synchronous functions are run outside of the main thread, otherwise they can prevent the main thread from running other asynchronous code. Async is a form of co-operative multi-tasking and like typical async web frameworks, Django will structure it so that the main thread has the best chance to keep running, so that pages that don't depend on sync can still work without being blocked by them.

Also, reading further into the documentation that was linked: The reason this is needed in Django is that many libraries, specifically database adapters, require that they are accessed in the same thread that they were created in. Also a lot of existing Django code assumes it all runs in the same thread, e.g. middleware adding things to a request for later use in views. Rather than introduce potential compatibility issues with this code, we instead opted to add this mode so that all existing Django sync code runs in the same thread and thus is fully compatible with async mode.

Specifically about that last point: async threads may be running on an executor that lives on a completely different thread to the one that spawned it (or if executor is of the "work stealing" kind), any threadlocals which may be available will no longer be or of a completely different value, which is why Django opted to use this mode to ensure that all those threadlocal sensitive functions are shunted off to a thread fully dedicated to them.  This should be the main reason for that, but other reasons I've listed also applies.

After the back and forth in the comments I feel I have a good idea of what kind of explanation you are after.
If you keep reading the documentation you quoted, in the immediate paragraph that follows, it wrote:

Rather than introduce potential compatibility issues with this code, we instead opted to add this mode so that all existing Django sync code runs in the same thread and thus is fully compatible with async mode. Note that sync code will always be in a different thread to any async code that is calling it, so you should avoid passing raw database handles or other thread-sensitive references around.

(Emphasis are mine in the above, and likewise in quotes below).
On top of ensuring that synchronous (blocking) function calls don't cause the main worker thread(s) to block as that would prevent everything else from being done (including other asynchronous IO that could be happening concurrently), the above explains the real reason why the documentation in Django insist that sync_to_async must be used.
A point from your question need addressing:

... but why we need to run sync function in a new thread in async context?

Your assumption here is wrong, at least with how Django is set up when it's running within an async context.  Along with the emphasis I put above and quoting from a couple paragraphs before the one you quoted:

If you use asyncio.run() or similar, it will fall back to running thread-sensitive functions in a single, shared thread, but this will not be the main thread.

Again, note the keywords here: "single, shared thread", not a new thread.  As for "why", this is to ensure that legacy synchronous applications that may not be thread-safe, or things that can be used in a multithreaded environment but has invariants that can't be violated, such as SQLite, where it "can be safely used by multiple threads provided that no single database connection nor any object derived from database connection, such as a prepared statement, is used in two or more threads at the same time."
Another point from your question need addressing:

And as I know since the GIL still exist accessing one object from multiple thread should be thread safe.

Again, GIL might only protect pure Python code, but it does absolutely nothing about C libraries that Python uses, because the invariants as specified by SQLite cannot be upheld by the GIL.
To ensure safer usage of an SQLite connection, it's typical to use threadlocals to establish a connection, where that connection object wouldn't typically be easily used in a different thread. While in Django's ORM usage of it, there simply don't support async yet, quote:

We’re still working on async support for the ORM and other parts of Django. You can expect to see this in future releases. For now, you can use the sync_to_async() adapter to interact with the sync parts of Django. There is also a whole range of async-native Python libraries that you can integrate with.

I will presume Django uses threadlocals within the dedicated sync thread (I am not expending time to look this up; you can go figure this out) to ensure that the connection set up inside that one dedicated thread don't get copied/cloned out of there which will violate SQLite's thread-safety invariant. And so, to have access to the database connection or to do ORM in Django, the use of sync_to_async() is a must.
Finally, the way Django has set this up has nothing to do with performance, but has everything to do with interoperability with non-sync and non-threadsafe code that is peppered within itself and elsewhere in Python's ecosystem.
So, if you want something "healthy" according to definitions given in your comment, Django shouldn't be your choice.

@Thanks for response! Now I understand why database operations should be wrapped with sync_to_async. Can you provide one more example about e.g. middleware adding things to a request for later use in views?

@PaleNeutron Think about it, if the middleware involves the use of sync_to_async(), naturally whatever things added thread locals will only be available to the thread it got added in, which would be the one and only thread that functions got sent to via sync_to_async(), right? So it follows that in order to use those things from the view, they will have to be pulled from the same thread, wouldn't it? So sync_to_async() should guarantee that because it's built for that.
